# JQ — Remove elements by value not index

Tags: arrays, json, jq, subtraction, blacklist

I need to delete all elements of `instances` that are either set to "three" or "five". Their index is not always the same:

```json
{
"address": "localhost",
"name": "local",
"vars": {
    "instances": [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```json
[10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30]
```

…and you want to remove all the `20` and all the `30`. Here's one way:

```
. - [20, 30]
```

> As well as normal arithmetic subtraction on numbers, the `-` operator can be used on arrays to remove all occurrences of the second array's elements from the first array.

See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions

In your case you could do:

```
.vars.instances -= ["three", "five"]
```

…which returns:

```json
{
  "address": "localhost",
  "name": "local",
  "vars": {
    "instances": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "four"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `|= . -` can be reduced to `-=` giving you `.vars.instances -= ["three", "five"]`.

Comment: @pmf Wow! Never occurred to me that this could be a thing. Many thanks. Will edit.